# Hit input value not long enough for date format when test in where clause

Tags: oracle, date, sysdate

```
TRUNC(SYSDATE) >= TO_DATE(REPLY_DATE || (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)+ADD_YEAR),'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Above script is one of the WHERE clause condition in my script, after condition addedm the whole script throw error `ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format`

I tried to execute with actual value in select query, it works fine

```
SELECT TO_DATE('28-06' || (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)+1),'dd-mm-yyyy') AS reply_date FROM DUAL;
```

return, 28-JUN-19

The column REPLY_DATE and ADD_YEAR are the columns hold value `28-06` and `1` repectively in table.

Comment: What datatype is `REPLY_DATE`?

Comment: @William Robertson VARCHAR2(5)

Comment: Why on earth do you store `DATE` values as `VARCHAR2`?

Comment: 28-06 = 28-JUN, will it cause any issue? As i convert the value using TO_DATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
TRUNC(SYSDATE) >= ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(REPLY_DATE, 'DD-MM'), 12 * ADD_YEAR)
```

`EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)` is not needed, because when you don't specify any year in `TO_DATE` then Oracle takes the current year.

How can you ensure that you **always** have to apply the current year? - consider hours around new years eve.